# converting monthly data into quarterly in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to convert monthly data into quarterly data in matlab using toquarterly function. I have 222 months but it converts to only 3 quarterly data figures. I feel the problem is in not identifying the frequency of the data correctly. How do I rectify this problem. The code used is

```
clear;
data=xlsread('dep_credit.xls');
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);
%z=data(:,3);
%Convert to time series using function fints
%myfts=fints(dates, data)
dates=((07/00/97:07/00/97+221))'; 
myfts1=fints(dates,x,'monthly');
myfts2=fints(dates,y, 'monthly');
%myfts3=fints(dates,z);
%convert to quarterly series
x0=toquarterly(myfts1,'CalcMethod', 'SimpAvg');
y0=toquarterly(myfts2, 'CalcMethod', 'SimpAvg');
%z0=toquarterly(myfts3);
%convert fts object to matlab object
x=fts2mat(x0);
y=fts2mat(y0);`
```

Comment: What does `dates=((07/00/97:07/00/97+221))'` return? I get `NaN`. Try to look at [Generate Sequence of Dates and Time](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-sequence-of-dates-and-time.html).

Comment: @Jørgen of course you get `NaN`, you divide 7 by 0, which is `NaN`. Everything else in that line is irrelevant after that. I think you can fix this by doing `dates = (datenum(07/00/97):datenum(07/00/97)+221);`, which is fully equivalent to doing `1:222+datenum(07/00/97)`, since `datenum` gives the number of fractional days. Might want to look at that zero month btb, that usually does not exist.

Comment: @Adriaan, I know, I was trying to indu mann to realize the problem. Inserted a link to date/time arrays.

Comment: try using dates=((07/01/97:07/01/97+221)), it will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Jorgen, as suggested in the referenced webpage, I tried using                                                                                                                                         A=datetime(1997,06,01);
B=datetime(2015,12,01);
C=linspace(A',B',222);
myfts1=fints(C',x,'monthly');
myfts2=fints(C',y, 'monthly');                                                                                   obviously it generates errors as fints only takes particular data types

Comment: This [question on matlabcentral](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/276495) seems to have an answer: `datenum(1997,1:222,1)`.